# How to access Label inside DataList which is inside another DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, datalist

There are 2 DataList `DataList2` and `DataList3` 
`DataList2` has `DataList3` and a `Button` and `lblOrderID`
`DataList3` has `lblQuantity` 
On Click of `Button` value of `lblQuantity` should be assigned to `qty`
**When i debug this code it shows qty is null?** 
Error : *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

```
protected void bremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button remove = (Button)sender;
    DataListItem row = remove.NamingContainer as DataListItem;
    DataList dat = (DataList)row.FindControl("DataList3");
    Label qty = (Label)dat.FindControl("lblQuantity");
    Label id = (Label)row.FindControl("lblOrderID");
    string oid = id.Text;
    string oqty = qty.Text;
    sqlqueries.UpdateOrder(oid, oqty);
    int k = sqlqueries.CancelOrder(oid);
    if (k != 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
Label qty = (Label)dat.FindControl("lblQuantity");
```

Although you use an individual `DataListItem` to find the nested DataList (with the NamingContainer), you then proceed to find a Label in `DataList3` itself, not an Item *in* DataList3.

It should be

```
Label qty = (Label)dat.Items[row.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblQuantity");
```